Firestore collection field with array filter always return empty
I am not sure why this query returning empty list
_firestore
        .collection('chat')
        .where('participants', arrayContains: {'userID': 'gg'})
        .snapshots()

My Firestore db.

Do I need to set any indexes I tried with participants.userID but no luck.
Without filter it's returning the value. Is it correct usecase for firestore? Or Do I need to change the structure ?

The array-contains operator only returns a document if there is an exact, complete match in the array. It can't do partial matches. The workaround is to add another array field with just the values you want to match on, e.g. participantUserIDs: ["gg"] and query on that.

ohh with that said all the objects from that array need to match, I was fighting with gemini and chatgbt. but They couldn't  answered this. Thanks man
